# R, igraph, is it possible to fill vertex with pattern

Tags: r, igraph

Drawing a graph with R and igraph, I'm using color to label vertex type. See code below. Is it possible to fill vertices with a pattern rather than a color so that the node types are distinguishable when viewed in color AND black and white?
I need 4 unique colors/patterns. The only palette from colorbrewer that fits is this one: http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=OrRd&n=4
However, for my sparse graph, its still difficult to differentiate the colors. Also, I'm color blind, which doesn't help. I wan to know if I can fill the vertices with stripes,hasing, polka-dots, anything other than color.

```
library(igraph)
library(RColorBrewer)
cols = brewer.pal(4, "Dark2") #looks good in color, not in bw
g <- sample_pa(20)
l <- layout_with_fr(g,niter=300)
plot(g,layout=l,edge.arrow.size=0,vertex.size=8,
     vertex.frame.color="white",vertex.label=NA,vertex.color=cols)
```

Comment: That does create a graph but it's not very reproducible. Would be better if you supplied a starting point that resembled your use-case.

Comment: If you don't respond to feedback, people will lose interest. I've been building test cases for potential avenues but the vagueness of the question makes me reluctant to post an answer.

Comment: This closely matches my use case and is totally reproducible. If you want the graph to be identical every time put "set.seed(777)" at the top

Comment: Why not differential with vertex shape rather than color? Since you require only four unique patterns, shapes should work.

Comment: So you want this randomly colored and patterned?

Comment: I want to stick with circles for consistency with other graph drawing, where the shape already signifies something.

Comment: Randomly colored and patterned is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your graph has 20 vertices.

```
> length(V(g))
[1] 20
```

The shape argument (see `?vertex.shape.pie` can apply a varying pie-"pattern" (or shape) in the form of a numerical specification of the relative segment sizes and varying colors:

```
values <- lapply(1:20, function(x) sample(1:5)) #segment sizes
colrs <- lapply(1:20, function(x) sample( c(heat.colors(4), "#000000FF"), 5))  # order of colors
plot(g, vertex.shape="pie", vertex.pie=values,
       vertex.pie.color=colrs,
       vertex.size=seq(10,30,length=10), vertex.label=NA)
```

[image]

You could make these "white" with "#ffffffff" or make them varying shades of grey. It is possible to pattern base graphics (which is the paradigm used by `plot.igraph` with arguments like:

```
rect(.8,.8,1,1, col=grey(.2), density=20, angle=45)
```

However, I don't see the use of the 'density' parameter in the `plot.igraph` code. If you want to do your own inspection, you will need to look inside the `igraph`-namespace:

```
ls( envir= as.environment("package:igraph") )
```